# Name not defined error when name is already defined in the same module

Tags: python, module, runtime-error

Check the following module.

```
# mod.py

class A:
   o = B()

class B:
   o = A()
```

I have exactly same module. The class layout is same. How do I define things like this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you really need these both to be class-level attributes? Are you sure you don't want them to be instance attributes, in which case you define them within each class's `__init__`?

Comment: We need them at class level. Otherwise its quite easier with `__init__`, I know that.

Comment: @Martijn gave you the correct approach, another is to split the classes into two files and then import them when needed.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: That would still lead to a circular import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `B` is not yet defined when the body of `class A` is executed (which is immediately).

Add `A.o` after `B` is defined:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    o = A()

A.o = B()
```

Answer (score 1):

(Note: what is being done is weird, but just answering the question)

You can set the attributes at runtime inside the module. It's a bit ugly, yes, but it's valid Python:

```
class A(object):
   pass

class B(object):
   pass

# setattr(B, 'o', A())
# setattr(A, 'o', B())
B.o = A()  # Making Martijn happy!
A.o = B()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print A().o
    print B().o
```

Comment: Why use `setattr()`? The attribute name is not dynamic here, you can just use `B.o = A()` and `A.o = B()`.

Comment: True. Unnecessary. No particular reason why I used `setattr()`. Maybe then name can be made dynamic using a module variable so easy to change later? :)

Comment: That's what I call a YAGNI; "You Ain't Gonna Need It". Put in a `setattr()` when you *actually* need it, not when you think you might need it at some point. :-)